# Trajectory MultiDOF to file

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm getting stuck trying to save the trajectory generate by MoveIt to a file.

The trajectory is generated correctly and the robot moves right in RViz.

```
moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
const double jump_threshold = 0.0;
const double eef_step = 0.01;
double fraction = move_group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory);
```

[image: image description]

Also, I can open a file and write that in it. But I can't obtain the data of the trajectory.

If I read the data with:

```
trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].position[6];
```

I get a value, that I don't know what it means, and also is only one point, no three for the X, Y, and Z of the joint.

If I try with:

```
Eigen::Affine3d t;
tf::transformMsgToEigen(trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[i].transforms[j], t);
```

I can compile my code, but I get an error when executing the program. The error code is -11.

```
[move_group_interface_tutorial-1] process has died [pid 19367, exit code -11, cmd /home/crasar/WS/fotokite_ws/devel/lib/moveit_tutorials/fotokite_move_path __name:=move_group_interface_tutorial __log:=/home/crasar/.ros/log/f8fe907a-cb06-11e8-bd7b-d89ef3923760/move_group_interface_tutorial-1.log].
log file: /home/crasar/.ros/log/f8fe907a-cb06-11e8-bd7b-d89ef3923760/move_group_interface_tutorial-1*.log
```

[Here is the workspace of my project.](https://github.com/grafoteka/Fotokite_arm)

And to launch it you need two terminals:

1. roslaunch fotokite_moveit demo.launch
2. roslaunch moveit_tutorials fotokite_move_path.launch

Thank you,
Jorge

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305133/trajectory-multidof-to-file/) by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2018-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is made of two answer:

- question #q277954 -> store data into file
- question #q246678 -> transform the link to the global pose

The solution is also in this [repo](https://github.com/grafoteka/Fotokite_arm).

```
// Store the points in a matrix
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // The solution is here: https://answers.ros.org/question/246678
  // To get the data without Eigen, the solution is here (line 460): https://github.com/kunal15595/ros/blob/master/moveit/src/moveit_core/robot_state/test/test_kinematic.cpp
  // To store all the points of the trajectory into a vector of vectors (matrix with x,y,z)
  // These are the necessary steps:
  // 1- Select the point in the trajectory (i)
  // 2- Set the robot on that pose (setVariablePositions && update)
  // 3- Obtain th3 values of the point from the link that is desired (kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("link"))
  // 3*- Also is possible for the orientation

  robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
  robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
  //ROS_INFO("Model frame: %s", kinematic_model->getModelFrame().c_str());
  robot_state::RobotStatePtr kinematic_state(new robot_state::RobotState(kinematic_model));

  std::vector<std::vector<double>> trajectory_pos(trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.size());
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> finger_state(trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.size());

  for(int i = 0; i < trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.size(); i++)
  {
      trajectory_pos.at(i) = {trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[0],trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[1],trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[2],trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[3],trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[4],trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[5],trajectory.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions[6]};
      kinematic_state->setVariablePositions(trajectory_pos[i]);
      kinematic_state->update();

      double finger_state_x = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("finger").translation().x();
      double finger_state_y = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("finger").translation().y();
      double finger_state_z = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("finger").translation().z();

      finger_state.at(i) = {finger_state_x, finger_state_y, finger_state_z};


      // This is from the original code. It prints the translation and orientation of the link in each position
      // Affine3D is a Matrix with 3 rows * 4 columns
      //const Eigen::Affine3d &end_effector_state = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("link_6");
      //ROS_INFO_STREAM("Translation: " << end_effector_state.translation());
      //ROS_INFO_STREAM("Rotation: " << end_effector_state.rotation());
  }


    // Store the points in txt file
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // The solution is from here: https://answers.ros.org/question/277954/
    // 1- Create a stream with all the data from the link coordinates.
    //    Each line has the 3 values separates by comma.
    // 2- When all the data is stored in the stream is time to open the file
    // 3- If the file is open correctly the data is copy in the file
    std::stringstream ss;

    for (unsigned i=0; i< trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.size(); i++)
    {
      ss
          << finger_state[i][0]
          << "," << finger_state[i][1]
          << "," << finger_state[i][2]
          << std::endl;

      if(i == (trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.size()-1))
      {
          std::ofstream outfile ("/home/crasar/points.txt",std::ios::app);
          if(!outfile.is_open())
          {
            ROS_INFO("open failed");
          }
          else
          {
              outfile << "There are a total of " << i << " points in the trajectory" <<std::endl; //<<count<<std::endl;
              //outfile<<finger_state[i][0]<<","<<finger_state[i][1]<<","<<finger_state[i][2]<<std::endl;
              //multi_dof_joint_trajectory.joint_names[0]<<std::endl;
              outfile<<ss.str()<<std::endl;
              outfile.close();
              ROS_INFO("File created");
          }
      }
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) with karma: 133 on 2018-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0